# Voltage dropping on pcb

Tags: voltage, pcb, voltage-regulator

So I have a 5 volt supply on a pcb and I have been asked to add another component to it, this component takes a strict 1.8 volts only. I would like to know types of methods I could use to perform the voltage drop with limited space and heat sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the 1.8 V component uses low power, a programabble regulator LM317 can do the job. Other possible methods are:
- zener diode
- zener diode + transistor
- DC-DC voltage converter modules

The best in my opinion is the LM317. You would need to describe the 1.8V component better so we could have an idea about the power dissipated by the regulator, maybe it would be necessary a heat sink.

**EDIT: For the requirements that you gave, I think that LM317 is the best option.**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvnTeg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Hey, that was my first thought exactly, but I was curious if there was another solution that wouldn't require a heat sink, the component that I am using is a  Telit JF2 GPS receiver. link: https://www.telit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Telit_Jupiter_JF2_Hardware_User_Guide_r4.pdf

Comment: @NicholasVellacott If you want to avoid a heat sink, you could use a switching power supply.  The issues are they arent as simple to implement as a linear regulator and they can be noisier. The latter may or may not be an issue depending on what the part is.

Comment: According to that spec sheet they show an XC6221.. but neither data sheet is overly easy to navigate,

Comment: @Trevor, I agree more of a pain than I would like.

Comment: AMS1117-1.8 can be a good alternative.

Comment: 3.2V x 37mA = 0.1184 W; LM317 can dissipate 0.25W without a heat sink. So you can use just a linear regulator without heat sink. Add capacitors in the output for additional ripple rejection.

Comment: @mguima yeah just the usual on the output and I like to on the input as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The different ways to step down voltage?

- Voltage divider network (ether resistive or with diodes etc)
- Zener voltage regulator
- Linear regulator
- Switch mode DC DC converter
- PWM with microcontroller and external transistor

None and all of them are correct, because we don't know anything about operating parameters. Current consumption, for instance. 
Other keyeords; Requirements for voltage ripple/noise level, temperature stability, overcurrent protection... Etc

Comment: Quick run down 
operating temp: -40 to 85
noise ripple: 1.75 to 1.85
current consumption: 37mA or 10mA for low power.

Comment: Duty cycle needed for your component? Do you need low power for the whole system?